# weekdays' duration using boost date

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

Is there a way to get only the no. of weekdays between 2 boost dates.

In the following, I'm only getting calendar days.

```
date begin_dt(2011,Aug,3);
date end_dt(day_clock::local_day());
days duration=end_dt-begin_dt;

std::cout<<"calendar days between begin & end date are: "<<duration<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to run a day_iterator from start to finish:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
int main()
{
    using namespace boost::gregorian;

    date begin_dt(2011,Aug,3);
    date end_dt(day_clock::local_day());
    days duration=end_dt-begin_dt;

    std::cout<<"calendar days between begin & end date are:" << duration << '\n';

    int cnt=0;
    for(day_iterator iter = begin_dt; iter!=end_dt; ++iter)
    {
        if(    iter->day_of_week() !=  boost::date_time::Saturday
            && iter->day_of_week() !=  boost::date_time::Sunday)
            ++cnt;
    }
    std::cout << "of them " << cnt << " are weekdays\n";
}
```

Comment: Make an `is_weekday` function, and this turns into a great example of how to use `count_if`.

Comment: `int result = std::count_if(begin_dt, end_dt, [](date& d) { d.day_of_week != boost::date_time::Saturday && d.day_of_week != boost::date_time::Sunday; });`.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose it's not so simple, `boost::gregorian::day_iterator` is not compatible with normal iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You could start substracting the number of days to the next week start, and deleting either 1 or two depending if you're on saturday or before, or sunday. Then, you can divide the rest of the days remaining by 7, multiply that number by 2, and substract to the days. You have to make a case for the remainder too. If it is 6 (saturday), you have to remove one more. Not easy, but you get the idea.

Comment: indeed, though I was hoping for a more direct way of doing it ;-)