# How to get the number of days between two dates using boost::date_time

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

Are there any APIs available in boost::date_time to get the number of days between two dates that is also calendar specific?

Example, Number of days between 2005/01/01 and 2006/12/31 would be 730 in a seven day calendar and would be 504 in a five day calendar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [weekdays' duration using boost date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340986/weekdays-duration-using-boost-date)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup: posix_time to the rescue

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/467c93aec7a5e5d1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_date.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using boost::gregorian::date;

    date a { 2005, 1, 1 }, b { 2006, 12, 31 };

    std::cout << (b-a).days() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

> 729 <sup>[1]</sup>

Use `posix_time::ptime` if you want to use gregorian date + time of day (hh:mm:ss.fffffff). `local_time::local_date_time` adds timezone awareness for this (to be correct about daylight savings e.g.)

---

<sub>**Trivia** *Incidentally this number is also the square of 27, and the cube of 9, and as a consequence of these properties, a perfect totient number, a centered octagonal number, and a Smith number. It is **not** the sum of four consecutive primes*</sub>

Comment: The sum of four consecutive prime + another (29) ;-)

Comment: @Nico OMG. I can't even <strike>math</strike> wikipedia anymore. [Fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30384988/revisions)

Comment: @sehe Keep math. Adding four odd primes yields an even number, and four consecutive primes including two can only sum up to 17.

Comment: Like if you vote this answer because of the trivia and not because of the answer itself.

Comment: Retweet if you like the comments.